# Laptop can get internet from other wifi, but not our home

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, laptop, desktop-computer

So my sister got a new laptop, and it has been having trouble getting onto the internet. So, it is getting an IP via the router's DHCP, and says it has internet connection.

But, when i try and ping the router, it is getting timeouts, and then every maybe 12 or so pings, it will get a reply, but in 500-2000 ms.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the wifi drivers, reset winsock reset, flushdns, iprelease/renew, deleted he arp cache etc. Uninstalled AVG, and I just can't figure it out for the life of me. It can connect to her hotspot, and her schools wifi, and everything else in our network works, except her laptop.

I have also reset and reinstalled windows, and still nothing. I have no idea, so any help would be great

Comment: Does your router allow her in? Many home routers have a setting that does not allow new devices to connect without explicitly being added. Check in its settings for active MAC address filtering or other such security settings.

Comment: Wireless mac filtering seems to be turned off

Comment: Also, the MAC Adress of the laptop is showing up in the Wireless Station Status list

Comment: I've seen some occasional issues with regards to WPA/WPA2 autodetection between some wifi adapters and some access points.  See if you can configure the laptop and/or the access point to WPA2 (not WPA/WPA2 Auto).